# Create dataframes from unique value pairs by filtering across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter values across multiple columns creating dataframes for the unique value combinations. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code that is failing (given dataframe df):

```
dd = defaultdict(dict)  #create blank default dictionary
values_col1 = df.col1.unique()   #get the unique values from column 1 of df
for i in values_col1:
    dd[i] = df[(df['col1']==i)]    #for each unique value create a sorted df and put in in a dictionary
    values_col2 = dd[i].col2.unique() #get the unique values from column2 of df
    for m in values_col2:  
        dd[i][m] = dd[i][(dd[i]['col2']==m)]  #for each unique column2 create a sub dictionary
```

When I run it I get a very long error message. I won't insert the whole thing here, but here is some of it:

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self,
>   key, method, tolerance)    1944             try:
>   -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    1946             except KeyError:
>
> ...
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1

Comment: Learn about numpy permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas `groupby` functionality to extract the unique indices and the corresponding rows of your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A']*4 + ['B']*4,
                   'col2': [0,1]*4,
                   'col3': np.arange(8),
                   'col4': np.arange(10, 18)})

dd = defaultdict(dict)
grouped = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
for (c1, c2), g in grouped:
    dd[c1][c2] = g
```

This is the generated `df`:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     0     0    10
1    A     1     1    11
2    A     0     2    12
3    A     1     3    13
4    B     0     4    14
5    B     1     5    15
6    B     0     6    16
7    B     1     7    17
```

And this is the extracted `dd` (well, `dict(dd)` really)

```
{'B': {0:   col1  col2  col3  col4
          4    B     0     4    14
          6    B     0     6    16,
       1:   col1  col2  col3  col4
          5    B     1     5    15
          7    B     1     7    17},
 'A': {0:   col1  col2  col3  col4
          0    A     0     0    10
          2    A     0     2    12,
       1:   col1  col2  col3  col4
          1    A     1     1    11
          3    A     1     3    13}}
```

(I don't know what your use case for this is, but you may be better off not parsing the `groupby` object to a dictionary anyway).

Comment: Thanks Alberto, how did you create "grouped" in the code above?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy that line. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution!